# mule udp connection with multicasting

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to set up a UDP connector in mule and can not figure out how to set to multicast using the configurations.
In the mule documentation there is a separate multicast connector but that is not available in Anypoint Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is Mavenized, you could include the following dependency in the pom.xml to utilize multicasting.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-transport-multicast</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Within your configuration, you might use the following for your multicast connector.

```
<multicast:connector 
    name="multiCastConnector" 
    receiveBufferSize="1024"
    sendBufferSize="1024"
    timeout="0" 
    keepSendSocketOpen="false" 
    broadcast="false"
    timeToLive="127" 
    loopback="true"/>
```

In your flow, you can reference this connector in your UDP endpoint.

```
connector-ref="multiCastConnector"
```

You will also need to ensure the following is included in your namespace in the configuration,

```
xmlns:multicast="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/multicast"
```

and in the schemaLocation.

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/multicast http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/multicast/current/mule-multicast.xsd
```